# deleteItem - The provided key element does not match the schema (Node.js)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to delete an item on dynamodb using the http api gateway with reverse proxy integration and lambda. This is what it says on the logs:

```
"message": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
"code": "ValidationException",
"statusCode": 400
```

This my schema:

[image]

I'm trying to delete `hello` with this in my lambda:

```
let PK = event.queryStringParameters.PK

const params = {
    Key: {
        "PK": {
            S: PK
        }
    },
    TableName: "myTableX"
};

dynamodb.deleteItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to delete item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        callback(null, {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "Deleted successfully"
        });
    }
});
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `event.queryStringParameters.PK` is undefined.

Comment: no, I checked and it's defined, I also tried using a string "hello" manually defined and get the same error @hoangdv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, You cannot delete all the items just by passing the Hash key, to delete an item it requires Hash + Range because that's what makes it unique.

Here is the reference link from DynamoDB documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#API_DeleteItem_RequestSyntax

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

This mean you have to provide both `PK` and `SK` value for your query, like:

```
const params = {
    Key: {
        "PK": {
            S: PK
        },
        "SK": {
            S: "SK value", // this value
        }
    },
    TableName: "myTableX"
};
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing, it's a simple partition key, I'm providing just the value for it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Provide your key schema, I guess it is compiled from `PK` and `SK`, it that right?

Comment: what do you mean key schema, I'm using the same exact example as here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#deleteItem-property

Comment: Mean, you have to provide both PK and SK. in your example, you just provide PK.

Comment: Yep that worked. Please update your answer with that so it's more explicit. Thanks for the help hoa. Will accept when you update it